# Using GHC with NVCC

Tags: haskell, linker, ghc, nvcc

As an alternative to [accelerate](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/accelerate), I'm trying to call CUDA code over Haskell's FFI.

Here's a simple program that fails to compile:

cuda_code.cu:

```
void cuda_init() {
    cudaFree (0);
    cudaThreadSynchronize ();
}
```

Test.hs:

```
foreign import ccall unsafe "cuda_init" cuda_init :: IO ()
main = cuda_init
```

I compiled with

```
$> nvcc -c -o cuda_code.o cuda_code.cu
$> ghc Test cuda_code.o
```

and got several linking errors (undefined reference to cudaFree, etc). This isn't terribly surprising, and the obvious solution (to me) is to link with NVCC using `-pgml nvcc`. (This worked when I was using Intel CILK+ in my C code: I simply changed the linker to ICC, and everything worked just fine.)

Howver, using NVCC to link results in the linking error:

```
ghc Test -pgml nvcc cuda_code.o
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Test.hs, Test.o )
Linking Test ...
nvcc fatal   : Unknown option 'u'
```

Running

```
strace -v -f -e execve ghc Test -pgml nvcc cuda_code.o
```

(is there an easier way?) I discovered `ghc` is calling `nvcc` with

nvcc ... -L~/ghc... -L... -l... -l... -u ghczmprim_GHC... -u ghc...

I assume the `-u` options are intended for [linking `gcc`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) (and apparently `icc`) with undefined symbols, something `nvcc` clearly doesn't like.

I have no knowledge about how GHC links files. Thoughts on how I can get GHC to link to my CUDA code?

**--------EDIT-----------------**

Someone suggested that I try linking with GCC (as usual), but pass in the necessary linker options to `gcc` so that it can link to the CUDA libraries. If anyone knows what these might be, this would probably work!

Comment: Just linking gcc with -lcudart doesn't quite cut it: I get undefined symbols for my functions declared in cuda_code.cu. Perhaps different .o formats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to make this work.

cudaTest.cu:

```
// the `extern "C"` is important! It tells nvcc to not 
// mangle the name, since nvcc assumes C++ code by default
extern "C" 
void cudafunc() {
  cudaFree(0);
  cudaThreadSynchronize();
}
```

Test.hs

```
foreign import ccall unsafe "cudafunc" cudaFunc :: IO ()
main = cudaFunc
```

Compile with:

```
>nvcc -c -o cudaTest.o cudaTest.cu
>ghc --make Test.hs -o Test cudaTest.o -optl-lcudart
```

I also tried giving GHC the option `-pgmc g++` and removing the `extern "C"` (which I expected to work), but got compile errors in some CUDA header files. There's probably some easy way to fix this so that you don't need to explicitly tag every function with `extern "C"`.

Answer (score 3):

GHC uses `/usr/lib/ghc/settings` to determine compiler and linker options, and per-package files like `/var/lib/ghc/package.conf.d/builtin_rts.conf` to determine package-specific linker options. (Custom directory installation will have them in `${GHC}/lib/ghc-${VERSION}/settings` and `${GHC}/lib/ghc-${VERSION}/package.conf.d` respectively.)

Here is what I found for the RTS:

```
ld-options: -u ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Izh_static_info -u
            ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Czh_static_info -u
            ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Fzh_static_info -u
            ghczmprim_GHCziTypes_Dzh_static_info
            ...
```

According to the `ld` man page, the `-u` option defines a symbol as an undefined `extern` that must be defined somewhere else.

As far as I know this is the *ONLY* package that has these custom `-u` options in the `ld-options:` section of `package.conf.d`.

These must be unfortunately translated for a compiler/linker that uses a different option interface.

Be so kind and keep people posted about it on [haskell-cafe@haskell.org](http://www.haskell.org/mailman/listinfo/haskell-cafe). I'm sure there are others trying something like this too!

Comment: I'm assuming that something like this has been done before, for example with http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cuda-0.5.1.0. It mentions looking for `nvcc` in $PATH.